# Should i use reCAPTCHA in react or any single page application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, recaptcha

I am creating a react application and I don't what spam accounts.
But I don't want to use Google reCAPTCHA because of data protection.
So I was wondering. Should I really use reCAPTCHA in react application?
Or is there other good solution or should I create my own reCAPTCHA?